# how to filter the paragraph in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XML document where filtering need to be applied on the "para" element

```
<multitest.document version="1" publication.number="356456" 
   filterusing="a">
   <life quotes>
     <para.set>
      <para change.bar="no" language="en_ww" filter="a">Your work is going 
       to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly 
      satisfied is to do what you believe is great work. 
       </para>
     </para.set>
     <para.set>
      <para change.bar="no" language="en_ww" filter="b">Your work is going 
      to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly 
      satisfied is to do what you believe is great work.
      </para>
      </para.set>
       <para.set>
       <para change.bar="no" language="en_ww" filter="c">Your work is going 
       to fill a large part of your life, and the only way to be truly 
       satisfied is to do what you believe is great work.
       </para>
       </para.set>
       </life.quotes>

    <general quotes>
    <para.set>
     <para>
     Where there is a will there is a way and never give up in life
     </para>
    </para.set>
   </general quotes>
```

In this example, the author has set the “filterusing” attribute to “a”, so in the block of so when the rule to check paragraphs with the filter attribute present (para/[@filter]) it matches the value to the filterusing value and processes the first paragraph. The others are ignored as they do not match the filterusing variable.

If the filterusing and filter both have been set to "a",then that para only should get processed and the other paras should get ignored and the ones which do not have a filter should be processed normally like general quotes

If no filter has been applied,then that para should be displayed as it is.

```
 <xsl:param name="filter"></xsl:param>
 <xsl:template match="//para[@filter]">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$filter=@filterusing">
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="filtering_1_atts">
     <xsl:value-of select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
   </fo:block>
 </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="@filterusing!='$filter'">
     <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="filtering_1_atts">
     <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
   </fo:block>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="filtering_1_atts">
        <xsl:value-of select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
      </fo:block>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

The para is not getting displayed even when both filterusing and filter have been set to "a".

I am new to this technology,So pls help me out.

Answer (score 2):

This statement `<xsl:template match="//para[@filter]">` sets the current node to `<para>`.

As a result, `<xsl:when test="$filter=@filterusing">` compares `$filter` to the `@filterusing` attribute of `<para>`.

You need to address the node that contains the `@filterusing` attribute:  `<xsl:when test="$filter=ancestor::multitest.document/@filterusing">`

**Second version of the question**: you've changed the template match to `<xsl:template match="//para/@filter">`. That tries to match only the filter attribute of the para nodes, so that won't work.

Comment: <xsl:param name="filter"></xsl:param>
 <xsl:template match="//para/@filter">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$filter=ancestor::multitest.document/@filterusing">
         <xsl:value-of select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
       </xsl:when>

Comment: You've changed the template match statement and introduced an error there.

Comment: <xsl:template match="//para[@filter]"> is also not working

Comment: Strictly speaking, `<xsl:template match="//para[@filter]">` doesn't set the current node to `<para>`.  It's the template rule that applies when the current node is `<para>`.  I.e., from XSLT 1.0: "The match attribute is a Pattern that identifies the source node or nodes to which the rule applies." (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Defining-Template-Rules).  Setting the current node to a particular `<para>` happens in the processing of some `xsl:apply-templates` (either actual or built-in) or in the processing of an `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Without applying <xsl:template match> ,the <xsl:apply-templates> and <xsl:for-each> are not working n moreover if <xsl:template match="para"> is kept,the complete paragraphs in the displayed output are becoming empty

Answer (score 0):

```
 <xsl:variable name="filterVariable" 
  select="multitest.document/@filterusing"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="para[@filter]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$filterVariable=@filter">
        <xsl:value-of select="para[@language=$active_language]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="not($filterVariable=@filter)">
        </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="para[$filterVariable=@filter]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

The above is the solution n it is working fine